# Pin Buffer Types

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, buffer

I'm going through the datasheet of this PHY Transceiver [LAN8742A](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/LAN8742)

On table 2.2, it is mentioned as buffer types.

I see a row called as O12, which stands for Output 12mA sink or Output 12mA source.

My confusion is how can the output can sink 12mA, when Output can only source current and not sink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My confusion is how can the output can sink 12mA, when Output can only source current and not sink?

This assumption is wrong.

Output O12 is able to source and sink 12mA.

As seen in the DC Specifications. Take note of the sign in both cases.

[image]

These kind of buffers are often impelemented as push-pull outputs.

Simplified view:

[image]

Image source: https://open4tech.com/open-drain-output-vs-push-pull-output/

---

> So, is this pin input or output? Because current is driven output of the pin as well as it sinks current internally to the IC

This pin is an output, in push and pull phase. An output needs a low impedance so that it can drive the signal. The direction of the current doesn't play a role.

An input on the other hand has a high impedance. Which means it won't impact the signal in any significant way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, is this pin input or output? Because current is driven output of the pin as well as it sinks current internally to the IC

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for the edit. "An input on the other hand has a low impedance." - You mean high impedance?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a connection is an output or an input doesn't depend on the direction of current, or the impedance. It depends on function.

An input accepts a signal from another device, an output sends a signal to another device. The voltage, current, direction of current and impedance are all determined by the particular interface. It's what the connection does that makes it an input or an output, not how it does it.